# Problems with TDA7850H

Tags: stm32

I have a problem with a TDA7850H.

The input is a 1 kHz sine wave generated by an STM32 microcontroller. A coupling capacitor removes the  DC component of the signal.

On the output balanced channel 1 of the amplifier I get this:

[image: Oscilloscope photo]

[image]

- The yellow channel is the input signal.
- The green channel is the balanced (not working) output channel of the amplifier, measured with a differential probe.

[image: Schematic]

Does anyone have some idea why or what to check?

Comment: What is the two channels of the oscilloscope connected to? Also, post schematics of your circuit.

Comment: Where is your load for the output? Put a 10 Ohm resistor on the output. 
Observe the test circuit in the datasheet.

Comment: How is generated the 1 kHz by STM32?

Comment: Is this a PWM amplifier ("bridge" power amplifier)? In that case, it would need some "L-C" filter?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used a [TDA7850](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7850.pdf), but if I had the problems you are having, here's what I'd check:

1. All grounds connected.  You have most of the P-GND pins floating.  Each is shown next to an amplifier output, but I expect they are all internally connected together.
2. All input pins connected.  You've left the unused inputs floating.  They can pick up stray signals.  For each input, connect a 1k resistor to ground, then from the other end a 100nF capacitor to one of the inputs.  That should keep the inputs from floating without putting DC on them.
3. Put a proper load on the output you are using.  That would be a 4 ohm resistor rated for 50 watts.
4. Proper heatsinking. The TDA7850  will burn as much (or more) power as heat as it supplies to the speaker(s.) You're going to need a huge heatsink with a good thermal connection to the amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Soved, a collegue of mine reversed the footprint in the Altium designer component library